# How to set TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType to "username" instead of "name" for Azure AD B2C user?

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c, owin-middleware

I have the following code to configure the process of authentication in my ASP.NET MVC web application, including the setting a claim to the user's "name" when validating the user's identity token received by the application.

(Note that I am following [this sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs))

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always
    });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
        MetadataAddress = String.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, DefaultPolicy),

            // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
            ClientId = ClientId,
            Authority = Authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = RedirectUri,
            RedirectUri = RedirectUri,

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
            },

            // Specify the claims to validate
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name"
            },

            // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
            Scope = $"{OpenIdConnectScopes.OpenId} {ReadTasksScope} {WriteTasksScope}"
    });
}
```

The "name" claim type maps to the user's `DisplayName`, which is returned when I use the code `User.Identity.Name`.

**How can I get `User.Identity.Name` to map to the user's Username, like in the below screenshot of an Azure Active Directory B2C user?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

**Here is the 2nd half of the answer above, which includes the code changes that were made:**

1. Add the line of code commented with "Added line here" so that the user's `ObjectId` is claimed:

   ```
   private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
   {
       // Extract the code from the response notification
       var code = notification.Code;

       string signedInUserID = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
       TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, notification.OwinContext.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase).GetMsalCacheInstance();
       ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(ClientId, Authority, RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);

       ///////////////////////////////////
       // Added line here
       ///////////////////////////////////
       // Add a custom claim to the user's ObjectId ('oid' in the token); Access it with this code: ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("ObjectId").Value
       notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("ObjectId", signedInUserID));

       try
       {
           AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, Scopes);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MyLogger.LogTrace("Failed to retrieve AuthenticationResult Token for user " + signedInUserID, MyLogger.LogLevel.Critical);
           return;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then later in the web application, when you need to get and use the user's `ObjectId`, do this:

   ```
   try
   {
       string signedInUserObjectId = ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("ObjectId").Value;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       ... This should never happen, but better safe than sorry ...
   }
   ```
3. And lastly, using the Azure AD graph client, you can get the user object using `ObjectId`, which contains the user name. The specific query you will need is `GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version`. You may need to get the `UserPrincipalName` or a `SignInName`, depending on your type of user. For more information, [see the "Get a user" section here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations).

Comment: Re # 3: For B2C users, the value will be in `SignName`.  My guess is UPN is a Azure AD property.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you can get the username into that property as B2C does not return that value.

---

You can still get this value but it will take more work.  B2C does allow you to return the "**User's Object ID**" which will come back as claim `oid`.  [Sample Token.](https://jwt.ms/#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ilg1ZVhrNHh5b2pORnVtMWtsMll0djhkbE5QNC1jNTdkTzZRR1RWQndhTmsifQ.eyJleHAiOjE1MjI2OTMxNzAsIm5iZiI6MTUyMjY4OTU3MCwidmVyIjoiMS4wIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2dpbi5taWNyb3NvZnRvbmxpbmUuY29tLzgwMDMzZGZkLTZlYWItNDJjNC1iZGYyLTRlMjIzZDRiMzk2Zi92Mi4wLyIsInN1YiI6IjcyNDcyN2NjLWI1NzAtNDkyMi1iMmZiLWI4ZTA0ZDAxNTZlMyIsImF1ZCI6ImQzOWJmOGJmLWRjMGEtNDdjNi04YzU1LWZiMGFhZGE1M2QyMyIsIm5vbmNlIjoiZGVmYXVsdE5vbmNlIiwiaWF0IjoxNTIyNjg5NTcwLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1MjI2ODk1NzAsIm9pZCI6IjcyNDcyN2NjLWI1NzAtNDkyMi1iMmZiLWI4ZTA0ZDAxNTZlMyIsInRmcCI6IkIyQ18xX1VzZXJuYW1lIn0.ji3pt6dMWVjzd6cMe3rVAf2q-JsyuXzIt3HxxB4Joif5OnRPGUPQkTwKe8_m8cpuSMXfRspsu0nRGEqY3xdEE2K1VPUJft7PAbP_qjCF4DgWrn0_ds5K-PLAQmK77TL3ckYqn6V_MnEHdsWZVoNAJTF9Swusw8ewNAOvLrUkNQpbDtCtnJ_YkfcxPmn3W8az72lsa5wrXssRKQaoe2pIgo8UuZYVf7tdVM3df9DWDHRHQUmBuDXUrumj1kra4gx_F-0s29aMybtNv-ryiJRobKlmXluk9VCVi7B_OGyz9KOSgCSq8wCwPssZGdEVUGu3_lAxhcFRJM2iJFAT37MaIg)

You can get the `oid` claim and then query Azure AD to get the username value.  See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42233154/185123) on querying Azure AD.

**Return User's Object ID**

[image: user's object id app claim screenshot]

---

Azure feedback item: [include username in JWT claims](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/545b6986-ae25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I can now confirmed that the user's objectId (`oid`) is there, since I was able to decode it using the tool `https://jwt.ms/`. How can I easily get the `oid` in the web application?

Comment: I have attempted `GET https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version=1.6`, but this unfortunately returns me an Error 401: Unauthorized. I also tried looking in the `TokenValidationParameters` object to see if there was an `ObjectIdClaimType` or similar object, but was not able to find it.

Comment: Actually, I was able to figure it out by adding a custom claim in my `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` callback: `            notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("ObjectId", signedInUserID));`. And the ObjectId can be retrieved anywhere in the code after that using: `string oid = ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("ObjectId").Value;` Turns out I don't need your help with this. Thanks spottedmahn!

Comment: You should provide an answer :) @Emilia.  Happy to help :)

Comment: I tried to edit your answer to include the code-related changes that I made, but 2 people rejected my edit. Sometimes I don't understand StackOverflow. lol. I'm not sure if you have the power to accept my edit of your answer, but if you do, please accept it, or let me know how I can improve it so that it is acceptable.